# Show attached media image if no thumbnail image detected

Tags: wordpress, post, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using

```
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){}
```

to check if the post have  thumbnail image,
but this

```
 echo get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
```

display the word

```
 Array
```

I need to show the attached image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get just one image in the post and use it as a thumbail, you might want to try this one:

Add this to you're functions.php :

> ```
> // Get URL of first image in a post
> function catch_that_image() {
> global $post, $posts;
> $first_img = '';
> ob_start();
> ob_end_clean();
> $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
> $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
>
> // no image found display default image instead
> if(empty($first_img)){
> $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
> }
> return $first_img;
> }
> ```

To call it just put

> `<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>`

in your template file within the loop.

I found this brilliant code from this [forum thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/retreive-first-image-from-post). Saved me a lot of times.

Comment: You cannot `echo` an array, that is why you get `Array` from `get_attached_media()` as this function returns an array of objects, not a string

Answer (score 1):

I found this, and it WORKS

```
        <?php 
        if( has_post_thumbnail() )
        {
            // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail
           echo ' <a href="';
           the_permalink();
           echo '" title="';
           the_title_attribute();
           echo '">';
           the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );
           echo '</a>';
        }
        else
        {
            $imgs = get_attached_media( 'image' );

            if( count( $imgs ) > 0 )
            {
                $img = array_shift( $imgs );
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $img->ID, 'thumbnail' );
            }
        }
        ?>
```

And all thanks and credit for @birgire on WPSE

Comment: i don't know how to full use this websites and really thank you @Pieter Goosen to make me attention of this ..... actually it is too cool to have new reputation . i was registered from years and can't enter to the chat... now i can :-) thanx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media)

Using

```
echo get_attached_media( 'image' );
```

should work.

Comment: Array ......again lol.... i think i did mistake , but i don't know where or how.
is there a problem if i work in localhost ?

Comment: Sorry did you add the postid in example?

Comment: this is in the while loop , the code must know what the id by it self , so do you have any idea about?

Comment: If you do `print_r( get_attached_media('image', $post->ID));` what is returned

Comment: Array ( [138] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 138 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2014-05-03 18:42:22 [post_date_gmt] => 2014-05-03 15:42:22 [post_content] =>  [post_title] => 28 [post_excerpt] =>

Comment: بلا بلا [post_status] => inherit [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => 28 [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2014-05-03 18:42:22 [post_modified_gmt] => 2014-05-03 15:42:22 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 634 [guid] => http://localhost/a/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/28.jpg

Comment: [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => attachment [post_mime_type] => image/jpeg [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) )

Comment: It should work. Either `$media = get_attached_media( 'image' );` or `$media = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID);`

Comment: i create this theme from the zero.... so i expect there is a registration for get attachment media in functions.php ... is it ?